# Wordpress Query posts wrap each item in a div rather than an li and show descendants of current page

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I am using the following to wrap through a list of posts as I want to display them within divs.

Despite using

```
    global $post;
    $currentPage = $post->ID;
```

and

```
    'post_parent'      => $currentPage,
```

Which has worked fine elsewhere. I can't get the page to only show children and grandchildren of this page.

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $currentPage = $post->ID;
    // Get posts (tweak args as needed)
    $args = array(
        'post_parent'      => $currentPage,
        'post_type'        => 'page',
        'orderby'          => 'menu_order',
        'order'            => 'ASC'
    );
    $posts = get_pages( $args );
?>

<?php foreach (array_chunk($posts, 1, true) as $posts) :  ?>
    <div class="column small-4 medium-4 large-4">
        <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I am using the code within a custom template.

I have also tried

```
                <?php
                global $post;
                $currentPage = $post->ID;

                $args=array(
                  'child_of' => $currentPage,
                  'post_type' => 'page'
                );
                $my_query = null;
                $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                echo $currentPage;
                if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                        <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image_or_video', true)); ?>
                        <?php $alt_text_for_logo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'article_name', true); ?>
                        <?php $short_description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'article_short_description', true); ?>
                        <div class="column small-12 medium-6 large-4 box">
                            <div>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" itemprop="url">
                                    <?php if( $img ): ?>
                                        <img src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt_text_for_logo; ?>" />
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                   <?php endwhile; } ?>
                <?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

but this lists the pages I want followed by what appears to be 10 other random pages from the site's root though it doesn't list every page from the site.

Comment: Have you tried the first variant of code, but replacing `'post_parent'      => $currentPage,` with `'child_of '      => $currentPage,` ? The function `get_pages` doesn't seem to have post_parent as a valid argument. Here's the reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Comment: Thanks that worked. I don't know why I didn't try that way around. You might as well claim the bounty as I wont get it back and someone else may grab it by putting in an identical answer.

Comment: Ping @DmitriyDemir. :) Looks like OP's prediction has come to pass. May as well take what you earned, no?

Comment: Hey, I've been away and now back. I've posted the answer, so please accept it when you have time :)

Comment: And thanks for pinging me, by the way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Originally posted this solution as a comment, because I wasn't sure it was the only change that was necessary. Turned out it is, so here's the solution:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $currentPage = $post->ID;
    // Get posts (tweak args as needed)
    $args = array(
        'child_of'         => $currentPage,
        'post_type'        => 'page',
        'orderby'          => 'menu_order',
        'order'            => 'ASC'
    );
    $posts = get_pages( $args );
?>

<?php foreach (array_chunk($posts, 1, true) as $posts) :  ?>
    <div class="column small-4 medium-4 large-4">
        <?php foreach( $posts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The function `get_pages` doesn't seem to have `post_parent` as a valid argument. So you need to use `child_of` instead.

[Reference to Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $currentPage = $post->ID;
    // Get posts (tweak args as needed)
    $args = array(
        'child_of '        => $currentPage,
        'post_type'        => 'page',
        'orderby'          => 'menu_order',
        'order'            => 'ASC'
    );
    $posts = get_pages( $args );
?>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_pages

Answer (score 0):

> To list All sub pages of current page

```
<?php
            global $post;
            $currentPage = $post->ID;
            $args=array(
              'post_parent' => $currentPage,//change
              'post_type' => 'page',
              'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
              'order'     => 'ASC'
            );
            $my_query = null;
            $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
            echo $currentPage;
            if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <?php $img = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image_or_video', true)); ?>
                    <?php $alt_text_for_logo = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'article_name', true); ?>
                    <?php $short_description = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'article_short_description', true); ?>
                    <div class="column small-12 medium-6 large-4 box">
                        <div>
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" itemprop="url">
                                <?php if( $img ): ?>
                                    <img src="<?php echo $img[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $alt_text_for_logo; ?>" />
                                <?php endif; ?>
                                <span><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
               <?php endwhile; } ?>
            <?php wp_reset_query();?>
```

> only change on code

```
   $args=array(
              'post_parent' => $currentPage,//change
              'post_type' => 'page',
              'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
              'order'     => 'ASC'
            );
```

which display all child pages of current page with their Menu order

```
About Us
Contact Us
Gallery
Testimonial
Blog
```